# D3.js: Text is not showing inside a circle(They are on the same level of an element-group). How do I bring the text to the front?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

The title says it all, [this](http://codepen.io/juanf03/pen/rWaLwK) is the codepen.  The text is not showing within the circles. How do I do to put the text on the front?. This is the code:

```
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 40 ];

    var w=600,h=600;

    var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                      .attr("width",w)
                                      .attr("height",h);
    //1st level:All circles group
    var circlesGroup = svg.append("g").classed("general-group",true);
    //2nd level: Group of circle and text
    var elementGroup= circlesGroup
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("g").classed("element-group",true);

    var circle=elementGroup.append('circle');

    var circleAttributes= circle
      .attr("cx", function(d,i){return i*80+40;})
      .attr("cy", h/2)
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("stroke","black")
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .classed("circle",true);


    //text to show
      elementGroup.append("text")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text(function(d) {
         return parseInt(d);
       }).classed('tweet-number', true);

      circle.on('click', function(d,i){

        svg.selectAll('circle').transition().duration(500).attr("r", 20);

      if(d3.select(this).attr("r")==20){
          d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).attr("r", 36);
        }else{
          d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).attr("r", 20);
        }

      });

    //adding background image
    var circlesSelection=svg.selectAll('circle');
```

This is the generated html which seems to be fine since the circle is at the same level of the text in the element group as it should be:

```
<svg width="600" height="600">
    <g class="general-group">
        <g class="element-group">
            <circle cx="40" cy="300" r="20" stroke="black" fill="white" class="circle"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" class="tweet-number">5</text>
        </g>
        <g class="element-group">
            <circle cx="120" cy="300" r="36" stroke="black" fill="white" class="circle"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" class="tweet-number">10</text>
        </g>
        <g class="element-group">
            <circle cx="200" cy="300" r="20" stroke="black" fill="white" class="circle"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" class="tweet-number">15</text>
        </g>
        <g class="element-group">
            <circle cx="280" cy="300" r="20" stroke="black" fill="white" class="circle"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" class="tweet-number">20</text>
        </g>
        <g class="element-group">
            <circle cx="360" cy="300" r="20" stroke="black" fill="white" class="circle"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" class="tweet-number">25</text>
        </g>
        <g class="element-group">
            <circle cx="440" cy="300" r="20" stroke="black" fill="white" class="circle"/>
            <text text-anchor="middle" class="tweet-number">40</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the `x` and `y` positions of the text elements:

```
//text to show
elementGroup.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){return i*80+40;}
    .attr("y", h/2)     
    .text(function(d) {
        return parseInt(d);
     })
    .classed('tweet-number', true);
```

Here is your CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOyrMM

The `<g>` element wrap its content and autosize according to the contents, but it doesn't *position* the contents.

That being said, an alternative is using `translate` to the groups, and not setting any position for the texts or the circles:

```
elementGroup.attr("transform", function(d,i){
    return "translate(" + (i*80+40) + "," + h/2 + ")"; 
});
```

The result is the same, check the CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVyVYy

Comment: great answer, I will try the 2nd approach as well just to learn, is there any way with d3 of positioning both vertically and horizontally without using css? and on the codepen you did the onclick for resizing the circle is not working anymore if I press on the number. The number is not expanding if the circle expands as well, should I use a transform over the element group?...what is the common approach in this case? I want to press anywhere on the circle and make it expand......

Comment: First: your code doesn't tell the text to expand. And for avoiding the number getting in the way of the click event, set "pointer-events" to "none" for the texts.